# Ruby join 2 arrays like in SQL

Tags: ruby, join

I would like to join 2 arrays in ruby like in sql but I don't know how.

For example,

```
array1=[[50,'2020-01-05'],[23,'2020-02-06']]
array2=[['2020-01-05',1],['2020-02-06',3]]
```

would be joined like

```
joinResult=[[50,'2020-01-05',1],[23,'2020-02-06',3]]
```

In SQL terms I would do the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM A, B WHERE A.DATE=B.DATE;
```

Edit:
The arrays are derived by the following commands:

```
array1=MySQLView1.all().to_a
array2=MySQLView2.all().to_a
```

Namely, the arrays are mysql views that I want to join.

Any ideas?

Comment: How many arrays do you expect array1 and array2 to each hold, and would you expect this to be a one-to-one?

Comment: There's no built-in method like that. For each element in `a` you have to find the corresponding element in `b` and combine their values. Either via [`assoc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#assoc-method) / [`rassoc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#rassoc-method) or by creating an intermediate hash. It would probably be cleaner with custom objects and named attributes. (so you have `a.date` just like `A.DATE` in SQL)

Comment: At a glance, I would say you probably shouldn't be using Arrays here. If you have a data structure with known attributes, like `a.date` and `b.date`, then these should probably be custom objects instead. If you share some wider context of what these arrays actually are, and how you're creating them, then maybe I can offer more concrete advice.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! The arrays are essentially, MySQL views that I would like to somehow join.

Comment: Why don’t you use an actual SQL join then?

Comment: How can I do an SQL join in ruby (sorry to ask but I am a beginner in ruby)?                                                                                   Do you mean the .joins() function? I tried MySQLView1.joins(:MySQLView2) but got error, because it required to define foreign and primary keys of the views which is not possible.

Comment: Can you post what you are actually doing rather than an obscure example. If this is truly mySQL we can certainly join your views but not based on what you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not what you are looking, but as far as I know you would need to do something similar to achieve what you want, so I would do something like below to solve this issue:

```rb
require 'date'

array1=[[50,'2020-01-05'],[23,'2020-02-06']]
array2=[['2020-01-05',1],['2020-02-06',3]]

def merge_arrays(arr1:, arr2:)
    arr1.each_with_object([]) do |v1, result|
        
        v1_date = get_date(v_arr: v1)
        flag_added = false
        arr2.each_with_object(v1) do |v2, v1|
            v2_date = get_date(v_arr: v2)
            if v2_date == v1_date
                flag_added = true
                (v2 - [v2_date]).map{|v| v1 << v} 
            end
        end
        result << v1 if flag_added
    end
end

def get_date(v_arr:)
    v_arr.each do |v|
        if v.class == String
            return v if is_valid_date?(str: v)
        end
    end
    nil
end

def is_valid_date?(str:)
   y , m , d = str.split('-')
   Date.valid_date?(y.to_i, d.to_i, m.to_i)
end


p merge_arrays(arr1: array1, arr2: array2)
```

You can test the snippet above [here](https://repl.it/languages/ruby?v2=1).

Hope this helps!